# Should I delete my own post if I find the answer, or I should answer in my own post?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

As you can see, I recently posted a question. But after a day I found the answer myself.

I'm confused about whether I should answer my own question, so that the answer can be helpful to other people who search for that problem? I don't have enough reputation to comment actually so I can only answer my own question. And this is my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183672/authorization-required-remote-server-returned-an-error-in-c-sharp-when-using-ht). I already answered.

But it is the proper way of answering my own question? Help me if am wrong.

Comment: Answer your own post!

Answer (score 6):

Answering your own question is perfectly valid.  However, instead of providing only a link for your answer, you should include the steps you took to solve the problem.  Links can and do go bad, so having the information cataloged here allows future users to be able to solve similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

You did the right thing by posting an answer to your own question. This way it can help others if they have the same problem.